# Options for pointing domains to the same code base with Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant, forge

just finishing up building a vehicle and customer management system for a car sales. Everything is pretty generic so was exploring the possibility of creating a service from it.

What sort of options are there for keeping and managing a single code base and database but only retrieving client specific data.

The app is API driven using Laravel and a VueJS front end.

My aim would be for a client to purchase a domain and then be able to point this domain to the Forge server IP as normal.

I would still have the site created on Forge, but would just have an ENV file within it that contained specific requirement data.

But they how could I get all these sites to use the same codebase? As in, I would want a single site set up that contained all the code but the various sites could use this?

Hope some of this makes sense, any information into keywords or links would be great for what i'm trying to achieve.